# Persisting Reference Throughout Recursive Calls

Tags: java, recursion, static

I have a custom Object that has some "counter" fields. This Object gets those fields incremented within a function that will be called recursively. So I need the Object to be created anew each time the function is called so that the counter fields are reset, but not created anew if the function is in a recursive call. Make sense?

Currently, I'm doing this by overloading the method so that it's not *true* recursion, but rather I'm passing the same Object with counters around so that my counts are persisted.

Basically, something like below is what I'm doing now:

```
static Counter count(Object parent) 
{
    Counter newCounter = new Counter();
    newCounter = count(parent, newCounter);

    return newCounter;
}

static Counter count(Object parent, Counter currentCounter) 
{
    Object cur = new Object(parent);

    if(cur.isChild())
        Counter.child++;
    else if(cur.isParent())
    {
        Counter.parent++;
        count(cur, currentCounter);
    }

    return currentCounter;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Or a way where I don't need the overloading? Oh, and I *do* need the main method to stay static, due to restraints I can't easily change elsewhere within the system.

Comment: Is this code threaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using a static variable:** (assuming only a single thread)

```
static Counter counter;

public static Counter count(Object parent) 
{
    counter = new Counter();
    count2(parent);
    return counter;
}

private static void count2(Object parent) 
{
    Object cur = new Object(parent);

    if(cur.isChild())
        Counter.child++;
    else if(cur.isParent())
    {
        counter.parent++;
        count2(cur);
    }
}
```

**Or for multi-threading:**

```
class ThisClass
{
  private Counter counter;

  private ThisClass() { counter = new Counter(); }

  public static Counter count(Object parent) 
  {
    ThisClass thisClass = new ThisClass();
    thisClass.count2(parent);
    return thisClass.counter;
  }

  private void count2(Object parent)
    ...
}
```

Comment: So either way, it seems there's no way to accomplish this using only one total method?

Comment: @JToland Well, if you're happy calling it as follows: `count(parent, null)`, you should be able to figure out how to modify your code to a single call, but personally I'd use one of the above (the top way in private projects, probably the bottom way in production code (if necessary)).

Comment: @Dukeling - Alright, cool. Thanks! If that's the best practice to accomplish something like this, I'm happy. I just didn't know if there was a "more recursive" way to handle what I was doing.